# Find the matrix representation of $ T $ in basis $B$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let T be a linear transformation from $R^2$ to $R^2$, with matrix representation in the standard basis of:

$[T]^e_e$ = $\begin{bmatrix}2 & 5\\3 & -1\end{bmatrix}$
Let $ B = \left \{ \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 2\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}4\\ 3 \end{bmatrix} \right \} $

Find the matrix representation of $T$ in basis $B$.

So in order to find the matrix representation of T in basis B I used the equation: 
$[T]^e_e= [I]^e_b[T]^B_B[I]^B_e$

I found $[T]^e_b$= $\begin{bmatrix}3 & 4\\2 & 3\end{bmatrix}$

I found the $[T]^b_e= \begin{bmatrix}3 & 4\\-2 & 3\end{bmatrix}$

I found $[T]^b_b$= $\begin{bmatrix}32 & 105\\25 & 55\end{bmatrix}$

Is this correct so far?

For the final step I will substitute each component into the equation. Am I on the right track so far?

Comment: Your $[T]^b_e=([T]^e_b)^{-1}$ is not correct ( we have a $-4$).

Comment: you're right.. I negate both terms on that diagonal...

Comment: Do I then multiply [I]$^e$$_b$ [T[$^b$$_e$ and B?

Comment: Got my final answer to be $\begin{bmatrix}32 & -42\\25 & 33\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

You notation is a bit confused for me.

If 
$$
B= \begin{bmatrix}
3&4\\2&3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is the matrix that transforms the standard basis vectors to the vetors of the new basis, than it is also the change of basis matrix from the new basis to the standard, and its inverse: 
$$B^{-1}= \begin{bmatrix}
3&-4\\-2&3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is the change of basis matrix from the standard to the new basis.

If 
$$
T_E=\begin{bmatrix}
2&5\\3&-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$ is the matrix that represents the linear transformation $T$ in the standard basis

than the same linear transformation is expressed in the new basis  as
$$
T_B=B^{-1}TB=\begin{bmatrix}
20&33\\-11&-19
\end{bmatrix}
$$